# Switch between windows & tabs in Linux?

Tags: rhel, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

do we have keyboard shortcuts to switch between tabs or windows, am looking for shortcuts similar to of those available in windows (ctrl + tab to switch btw tabs & Alt + tab  to swtich btw windows).

Note: RHEL5.8 is accessed via CITRIX XENAPP as a window in windows xp

Comment: Which UNIX-like operating system are you connecting to, and which windowing environment is it running  (e.g. AIX and CDE, or Ubuntu Linux and Gnome 3 with Mutter, etc.)

Comment: we use RHEL 5.8, and this server we access via CITRIX machines to launch sessions

Comment: am looking for keyboard shortcuts to switch btw tabs and windows

Comment: ```Alt + Tab``` should work in nearly any WM. But the ```Alt``` is an escape-char for CITRIX imho. Just Change the Shortcut to something else like shown in the answer from justbrowsing

Comment: how do i answer this question am not finding 'POST YOUR ANSWER' tab ?

Comment: read [help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), once [on hold] is removed will post answer

Answer (score 4):

CITRIX isn't a **Window Manager**.

It looks like **Gnome2** is the default WM for **RHEL 5.8** but I can't find anything that explicitly states that.

Gnome2/Mate (Metacity/Marco):
`System -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts`

Set the shortcut for **Move between windows, using a popup window** (default is `Alt+Tab`). It's possible you are using `Compiz` or another WM though, so figure that out.

[image: metacity task switcher]

However, noticed you mentioned `konsole`, the official KDE terminal emulator. This suggests you may be using `KDE`. To switch tabs in `konsole` the default is <kbd>Shift+RightArrow</kbd> or change it `Settings -> Configure shortcuts -> Next Tab`.

[image: konsole keyboard shortcuts]

To switch windows in KDE `Alt+Tab` or change it `System Settings -> Window Behavior -> Task Switcher -> All windows`

[image: plasma task switcher]

Comment: to be specific i use citrix xenapp to launch session

Comment: Xen App isn't a [Window Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) either. However, [this document](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/receiver-linux-blackfoot/linux-config-keyboard-shortcuts.html) might be of some use to you.

Comment: following link will help in answering above question, link :[support.citrix](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/receiver-linux-12-1/linux-config-keyboard-shortcuts.html)
just to summarise from link, 

when remote desktop is not running in full screen mode

(switch between tabs is ALT+MINUS SIGN, and ALT+SHIFT+PLUS SIGN), 

(switch between window is SWITCH+RIGHT ARROW KEY, and SWITCH+LEFT ARROW KEY)


when remote desktop is running in full screen mode (CTRL+F2 will enable full screen mode)

(switch between window is ALT+TAB, and ALT+SHIFT+TAB)

Comment: you literally saved my life. default alt+tab style was so hard to parse :) small icons is where its at